# Am I correctly finding the polar graph of r = cos(4θ)?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

What I did was find an incriminator, so I set the inner to $π/2$.

$4θ = π/2$

$θ = π/8$

So the table goes:

$θ = 0, π/8, π/4, 3π/8, π/2, 5π/8$

and evaluating the functions those polar values I get the r’s to be:

$r = 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0$

So the pairs are:

$0,1$

$π/8,0 $

$π/4,-1 $

$3π/8,0 $

$π/2,1 $

$5π/8, 0$

When I graph these I am confused where $π/4$, $-1$ would go. Very unsure if I am doing ant of this right.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Generally, if you have a point at $-r$ and $\theta$, it would go wherever $r$ and $\theta+\pi$ (or $r$ and $\theta-\pi$) would go.  So $r = -1$ and $\theta = \pi/4$ is equivalent (on a polar graph) to $r = 1$ and $\theta = 5\pi/4$.

Comment: You should get a flower-looking graph.  How many petals does it have?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you naively get a negative radius, that indeed means going to $\theta+180^\circ$ and using the absolute value of $r$.

Next, I suggest for this curve you use smaller step sizes, perhaps $\frac{\pi}{16}$ or even  $\frac{\pi}{24}$.  The work involved is less than you think because by the time you get to $\pi/4$ you begin retracing curve segments you already have.

Comment: So radius will always be considered under absolute values? Is that what I am missing?

Comment: Not quite.  When the radius is "supposed to be negative" you do take the absolute value, but you go in the opposite direction of $\theta$.

Comment: So for π/4,−1 that would be -π/4,1?

Comment: How about graphing "i"?

Comment: No, $(\pi4,-1)$ is the same point as $$5\p/4,1)$.  You add (or subtract, it is the same thing here) $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! so when I have a negative 'r' that means make it the positive distance 'r' and then invert the the theta, so the inverse of π/4 is 5π/4, because that's its mirror image, right?